# Accidentally deleted the apt.deb file after SSHing into my EC2 instance

Tags: apt, amazon-ec2, deb

Accidentally deleted the `/ec2-user/apt.deb` file.

This is after SSHing into my EC2 instance with username `ec2-user` with the following command:

```
ssh -i <pem file path> ec2-user@ec2-54-176-4-151.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

What does this `apt.deb` file do, and how can I go about generating a new one?

Comment: There is no apt.deb file inside ec2 instances by default. This is something that was created by you or the person who created the AMI.

Answer (score 0):

A `.deb` file is a Debian package. Usually, you don’t deal with them directly. The typical command which uses them is `apt` (it is a coincidence that your file is `apt.deb`), then, if you type `apt install apt`, `apt` will check if a newer version of `apt` is available. If it is the case, get `apt.deb` and install it. Then the `apt.deb` is no longer useful.

Comment: When I run `apt install apt` it says that the command `apt` is not found. Is this related to me deleting the `apt.deb` file?

it appears the command to install stuff is `yum`, not `apt`.

Comment: `apt` is on Debian (and derivatives like Ubuntu). `yum` is the RedHat equivalent, but it uses `.rpm` files instead. If you have a RedHat (or derivative), you won’t need `.deb` files or the `apt` command.